# intro.js callback not firing when attached to window - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, intro.js

I am not sure if its because I have attached intro.js to the `window` but the tour it self and functions work ( `.start()` `.exit()` ect ) but the callback functions are not firing.

I am using Laravel 5.5 so in my app.js file that gets complied I have:

```
import introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';

window.introJs = introJs;
```

Then in my blade template I have

```
@section('js')

<script type="text/javascript">

  var doneTour = localStorage.getItem('doneTour') === 'yeah!';

  if (!doneTour){
    window.introJs.introJs().start();
  } 

  // add a flag when we're done
  window.introJs.introJs().oncomplete(function() {
    alert("end of introduction");
  });

  // // add a flag when we exit
  window.introJs.introJs().onexit(function() {
    alert("exit of introduction");
  });


</script>

@endsection
```

The the script I use in blade is injected after the app.js. I get no errors and the initial window.introJs.introJs().start(); works and the tour starts. But when I exit or complete it, the other functions do not fire. Does this have to do with Laravel or using `window`?

I have tried just using `introJs.introJs.start()` but unless I attach it to the window I cannot use it in a blade files

Answer (score 3):

For some reason its not in the docs but you in some cases you need to make introJs.() a variables for the callbacks to work.

```
var doneTour = localStorage.getItem('doneTour') === 'yeah!';

  var intro = window.introJs.introJs();

  if (!doneTour){
    intro.start();
  } 

  // add a flag when we're done
  intro.oncomplete(function() {
    alert("end of introduction");
  });

  // // add a flag when we exit
  intro.onexit(function() {
    alert("exit of introduction");
  })
```

Comment: I can confirm this is still the case with the latest (December 2020) release, and the documentation still doesn't explain it. In fact, if you look at the demos in their GitHub you'll find they themselves are doing exactly this:

[https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/callbacks/onbeforechange.html](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/callbacks/onbeforechange.html)